# User32.dll : SendMessageTimeout invoke is crashing Thompson One desktop client

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I have a desktop app that was running well smoothly until now: when i installed [Thompson One Desktop Client](https://www.thomsonone.com/DirectoryServices/2006-04-01/Web.Public/Login.aspx?brandname=www.thomsonone.com&version=3.7.9.18833&protocol=0). Once i installed the Thopson client and logged in into it and the desktop app is running, desktop app tries to get the GET_TEXTLENGTH of the handle of Thompson client and the call crashes the Thompson cleint.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    public const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    public const uint SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
   public const uint SMTO_BLOCK = 0x0001;
   public static uint DEFAULT_SENDMESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 250;

   [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern Int32 SendMessageTimeout(UIntPtr hWnd, uint lMsg, UIntPtr wParam, UIntPtr lParam,
       uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);


   public static string GetWindowText(UIntPtr hWnd, int cchMax, out bool bSuccess)
   {
       bSuccess = false;
       StringBuilder text = null;
       UIntPtr lResult = UIntPtr.Zero;
       if (Win32Interop.SendMessageTimeout(hWnd,
           Win32Interop.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH,
           UIntPtr.Zero,
           UIntPtr.Zero,
           Win32Interop.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG | Win32Interop.SMTO_BLOCK,
           Win32Interop.DEFAULT_SENDMESSAGE_TIMEOUT,
           out lResult) != 0) // This call is crashing Thompson One client.
       {
           // Process 
       }
   }
```

Can somebody help me figuring out what is going on??

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: I guess implicit in what @Hans says is that your code is not to blame for this. You need to ask the Thomson One devs why this is happening.